# Autoware.ai codebase and Is autoware.ai still actively maintained?

Tags: ros-melodic, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I would like to work on autoware.ai and trying to understand the code base. Is there any documentation to understand the codebase or any video tutorials?

Also, may I please know if autoware.ai is still actively maintained by the community?

Please advise!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/353782/autoware.ai-codebase-and-is-autoware.ai-still-actively-maintained?/) by [omkard](https://answers.ros.org/users/51732/omkard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 64 on 2020-06-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The only system level documentation I have found for Autoware.ai are these 3 year old documents: https://github.com/CPFL/Autoware-Manuals/tree/master/en
Take them with a grain of salt. There are some videos scattered around youtube that contain some information.

Considering the [planned end of life](https://discourse.ros.org/t/end-of-life-dates-for-autoware-ai/13750) for Autoware.ai coinciding with the [end of life](https://www.openrobotics.org/blog/2020/5/23/noetic-ninjemys-the-last-official-ros-1-release) of ROS1, your best bet for development would be to start looking into [Autoware.auto](https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto) the updated ROS2 version. The documentation is much more comprehensive, but the current capability is lacking compared to Autoware.ai.

---

Originally posted by [Patrick N.](https://answers.ros.org/users/47634/patrick-n./) with karma: 65 on 2020-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [omkard](https://answers.ros.org/users/51732/omkard/) on 2020-06-01**:
Hi @Patrick N.

Thanks for sharing the information you know. The documents in the link are more on how to use the Autoware Software. And, it is same with the videos on YouTube.

I have spent more than 5 months playing around with Autoware.AI and the capability it provides is huge. So, want to work with Autoware.AI. Please let me know if you encounter more on this.

Thank you very much!

**Comment by [Sam123](https://answers.ros.org/users/96030/sam123/) on 2022-04-01**:
Hi @omkard
I am newly trying for  autoware.ai(1.11.1),i am facing issue after ./colcon_release command.it would be better for me if you provide some guidance,i have already posted query(398362).
https://answers.ros.org/question/398362/vehicle-model-not-added-in-rvizautowareai-111/

thanks in advance